# How to drive Interface Builder with AppleScript?

Tags: macos, interface-builder, applescript

I want to programmatically create NIB (or XIB) resource files - like resource import tool. Making XIB file manually is not impossible, it is XML-based file, but there are too many unspecified items.

So, I'd like to use AppleScript to drive IB itself and create the resources with it, but I fail to do so - I can't create any new items and it keeps reporting that it cannot add *this* object to *that* container. Does anybody have any experience with that, or some good example that I can use as a starting point? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think Interface Builder is scriptable, but perhaps you could have an script which writes a file with the generic IBFile contents and then just change around some vars.